# Update column in .shp from .tab with QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, mapinfo, tab

Is it possible to perform in QGIS an "update column" on a .shp table with data from a MapInfo.tab having one field apparently in common?

One of the greatest uses of QGIS (for me) is the availability of working with different types of archives simultaneously (.tab, .shp) without having to change from one program to another or having to convert everything into one format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly simple task.

1. Load both datasets into QGIS
2. Join the two datasets using the column they both share. There are
   a lot of tutorials on joining on the internet. I.e.:
   http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php or
   https://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/joining-layers-in-qgis/
3. Now you just need to use the Field Calculator (http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) to create a new field in the shapefile, and put the value from the TAB file into it (it will be listed under "Fields and Values")

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear response. It is so simple that only with your first step the task was accomplished.